# Como saber o número de "filhos" de uma classe?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Por exemplo, utilizando um `for`:

```
var children = numero_de_filhos_de_uma_classe_qualquer;
for (i = 0; i <= (children); i++){
    document.getElementsByClassName("classe")[i];
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="classe" ></div> // Filho Número 1
<div class="classe" ></div> // Filho Número 2
<div class="classe" ></div> // Filho Número 3
<div class="classe" ></div> // Filho Número 4
```

Existe como fazer isso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar `.children` para contar o número de filhos de uma classe, exemplo:

**Exemplo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abfurlan/vL232/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="classe">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var minhaClasse = document.getElementById('classe');
alert(minhaClasse.children.length);
```

---

#### Após edição da pergunta

**[Exemplo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/abfurlan/rKu2w/)**

```
filhos = document.getElementsByClassName('classe');
for(var i = 0; i < filhos.length; i++){
 console.log(filhos[i]);
}
```

---

**Ou, para ficar o mais próximo de sua pergunta**

**[Exemplo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/abfurlan/rKu2w/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="pai">
    <div class="classe" >Filho número 1</div> 
    <div class="classe" >Filho número 2</div> 
    <div class="classe" >Filho número 3</div> 
    <div class="classe" >Filho número 4</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var pai = document.getElementById('pai');
var filhos = pai.children.length;

for(var i = 0; i < filhos; i++){
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("classe")[i]);
}
```

Comment: Seu exemplo não é bem o que eu queria, mas especifiquei melhor na minha resposta editada.

Comment: @SamirBraga editei a resposta, verifique se resolve o problema